# Multi-part Identifier could not be bound exception

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

As a note I have searched around for quite a bit but could not seem to grasp on how to fix it still. I am still learning the ins and outs in SQL server so please be patient with me.

I want to get a desired output of quantity from two tables but when I start to add the subquery into my statement I would get this error:

> The multi-part identifier "OD.Menu Name ID" could not be bound.

This is the statement that I have.

```
Select IT.[Item Name], SUM(OD.Quantity) * SI.Quantity as QTY from [Order Detail_T] as OD, 
dbo.SumOfIngredientsQty_V as SI
join [Ingredients Qty_T]
on [Ingredients Qty_T].[Menu Name ID] = OD.[Menu Name ID]
join Ingredients_T as It
on [Ingredients Qty_T].[Ingredients ID] = IT.[Ingredients ID]
where SI.Quantity in (Select SumOfIngredientsQty_V.Quantity as SI from SumOfIngredientsQty_V)
Group by IT.[Item Name]
```

I have also created a view that correlates to the above statement:

```
create view SumOfIngredientsQty_V
as
Select [Item Name], Sum(Quantity) as Quantity from [Ingredients Qty_T]
join [Ingredients_T]
on [Ingredients Qty_T].[Ingredients ID] = Ingredients_T.[Ingredients ID]
group by [Item Name]
go
```

Can someone enlighten me on why I would get the "could not be bound" exception. Also if need be I can include the relationship of the tables.

**Edit** Here are the relationships (I could not upload an image but I hope this will do)

```
Ingredients_T : (PK) Ingredients ID, Item Name
Ingredients Qty_T : (FK) Menu Name ID, (FK) Ingredients ID, Quantity
Menu Name_T : (PK) Menu Name ID, Price, Menu Name
Order Detail_T : (PK) Order Detail ID, (FK) Order ID, (FK) Menu Name ID, Quantity

Ingredients_T > Ingredients Qty_T < Menu Name_T > Order Detail_T
```

The (<) signify where the PK goes to.

Comment: @bummi If it does not have a column how would I go about adding the column?

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling on `OD.[Menu Name ID]`  Make sure that you have not omitted an underbar or any whitespace.

You can output the column names as SQL Server has them stored by using a query like:

```
select c.name as colname, t.name as tablename
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name like '%Menu%'
order by tablename
```

Above query restricts columns and tables to those that have a column with "Menu" somewhere in the name.

Comment: The spelling checks out. Also I did the above query and if what I am understanding you want me to see if Menu Name ID does indeed corresponds to the Order Detail_T table to which it does. So if it does have a column what could be the issue?

Comment: @YoHanYolo - what happens if you try a simple `select top 5 OD.[Menu Name ID] from [Order Detail_T] OD`

Comment: It would just list the first top 5 entries for Menu Name ID.

Comment: I was hoping you would actually run it and post the results here(or just report if it actually worked).  It's one of the simplest statements involving the field name that is throwing the error.  I couldn't see any obvious syntax errors in your code, so I was wondering if that statement would also throw an error.  If it does not, then slowly building in complexity should reveal the cause of your error.

Comment: The code can run perfectly fine without the subquery added to it. Its only when I add it do I get a conflict with that specific line. Question, is it possible to multiply using an aggregate function (Sum()) along with the subquery how I have it? Maybe the problem lies within that.

Comment: I ended up finding an alternative route to do the computations by creating 3 views and combining them. Thank you for trying to help!